# trying to send a state object on to another node through a flow

Tags: corda

I need an object to be distributed around 3 nodes on my network

So i have 2 flows, A sends Data to B and ledger is updated. i then want a flow to "forward" the same data on to another node, B sends Data to C.

if i copy the object then i have 2 entries of the data in my vault:

```
    // get data from my query (assume only one piece of data)
    val queryResults: Vault.Page<DataState> = serviceHub.vaultService.queryBy(query)
    val states: List<StateAndRef<DataState>> = results.states

    // We create a transaction builder and add the components.
    val txBuilder = TransactionBuilder(notary = notary)

    // Loop our chunks
    for (dataState in states) {
        val data = dataState.state.data.copy(participants = listOf(ourIdentity, otherParty))
        txBuilder.addOutputState(data)
    }

    // Add the command to the transaction.
    val command = Command(DataContract.Commands.Action(), ourIdentity.owningKey)
    txBuilder.addCommand(command)

    // We sign the transaction.
    val signedTx: SignedTransaction = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(txBuilder)

    // We finalise the transaction and then send.
    subFlow(FinalityFlow(signedTx, otherPartySession))
```

How do i "forward" it on in a new flow without duplication?
and BTW A wont be available when I send between B and C

Im guessing this is definitely wrong because its not initial:

`val signedTx: SignedTransaction = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(txBuilder)`

Comment: Can you explain your use-case? Why can't you share the state in a single transaction with all 3 nodes?

Comment: Node C will not be available during the A to B transaction

Comment: or during the flow from A to B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `SendStateAndRefFlow` (the counter-party nodes must call `ReceiveStateAndRefFlow` in a responder flow):

```java
SendStateAndRefFlow(otherSideSession: FlowSession, stateAndRefs: List<StateAndRef<*>>)
```

Comment: this is great, however i want the transaction from B to C to be a ledger update and persisted. Also i am getting a "Tried to access ended session SessionId(toLong=-{ID}) with empty buffer"

Comment: You can then use `SendTransactionFlow(otherSide: FlowSession, stx: SignedTransaction)`, your responder node must call `ReceiveTransactionFlow`.

Comment: how do i get my TransactionState into a SignedTransaction again?

Comment: When the responding node calls `ReceiveTransactionFlow` it should call it with parameter `StatesToRecord = StatesToRecord.ALL`; this way the node will register the transaction and `ALL` states that are inside that transaction. The default value is `StatesToRecord = StatesToRecord.NONE` which means register only the transaction (and `NONE` states).